# What is the Most Efficient way to Place Strings to Array from .txt

Tags: c#, arrays, string, text

I have a text file with about 30 words (of varying length). I'm trying to bring all of those words into the program and store them into an array of 'x' elements (x being the number of words).

Any help? I'm literally on day 2 of learning.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hangman {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            //StreamReader myWordList = new  StreamReader("WordList.txt");//string stringArray[] = StreamReader(WordList.txt);//.WordList.txt;

            String myWordArrays[] = File.ReadAllLines(@
            "C:\Users\YouTube Upload\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hangman");

            Console.WriteLine(myWordArrays[2]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the complete code (above) - I'm getting these errors:

```
Error   1   Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type.  c:\users\youtube upload\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Hangman\Hangman\Program.cs    16  32  Hangman
```

And

```
Error   2   Invalid expression term '=' c:\users\youtube upload\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Hangman\Hangman\Program.cs    16  35  Hangman
```

I don't really understand that, because I'm calling it like I should be (or so I would think? o.0)

And this:

```
Error   3   ; expected  c:\users\youtube upload\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Hangman\Hangman\Program.cs    16  35  Hangman
```

also this one

```
Error   4   ; expected  c:\users\youtube upload\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Hangman\Hangman\Program.cs    16  37  Hangman
```

Forgive my horrible formatting here - I'm new to this site and am just getting used to it all. :(

Comment: Is the number of words always 30, or can it vary?

Comment: Are the words separated by lines or all one one line separated by white space? If the former, `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("WordList.txt");` will give you a string array. If the latter, something as basic as  `File.ReadAllText("WordList.txt").Split(' ');` will give you a string of the file contents, split by whitespace to give an array of strings.

Comment: @Newbie The edit you've just posted features a possible answer, is something wrong with it? If not, you'd be better placed leaving the original question and posting your own answer to your question (which is allowed and even encouraged on this site).

Comment: @William - yes, it can vary. I just went to a site with a list of random words and copy/pasted, and each are on separate lines. 

I have updated my post with new code. The stuff I had up there earlier was a mess. It still is not working and now giving me all kinds of errors. 

I tried using File.ReadAllLines("WordList.txt"); but that didn't work, so I specified and still doesn't work. :(

Comment: I have added an answer for use with newlines :)

Comment: @Newbie You need to state how it isn't working, ideally posting a complete sample to demonstrate the issue, and at the very least any exception details you are getting (if any).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - thank you. I was going to add it as a comment - the new code (once I figured out the ReadAllLines thing), but I spent a lot of time hitting the 'space bar' on the first comment and didn't want to go through that again. LOL

Comment: Your array variable is incorrectly declared, I didn't spot that before. It should be this: `string[] myWordsArray = File.ReadAllLines...` not `string myWordsArray[]`. This issue is probably causing the cascade of other issues, because so far as I can tell the rest syntactically looks fine.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth AHHHH - my goodness, thank you. :)

Comment: @WilliamMoore Thank you for your answer. I will give those all a go and see what in the world they do for me. lol. :)

Answer (score 3):

Get values from file like this :

```
string[] myWordArrays = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\YouTube Upload\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hangman\yourfilename");
```

Your whole program :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hangman {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string[] myWordArrays = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\YouTube Upload\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hangman\yourfilename");

            Console.WriteLine(myWordArrays[2]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. What mistakes have you made in this line of code

```
String myWordArrays[] = File.ReadAllLines(@
            "C:\Users\YouTube Upload\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hangman\");
```

1. Incorrect variable declaration. Correct one is

   `string[] myWordArrays = ...`
2. '`@`' sign should be placed right before string that contain escape characters and should be on a same line. What if line is too long? Then you can move *both* this sign and the string to a next line.

`string[] myWordArrays = File.ReadAllLines(
@"C:\Users\YouTube Upload\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Hangman");`

3. File.ReadAllLines method accepts only full path and not a relative one. To point to a file that is located in the same folder where executive file is stored (bin folder) you can use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() method. So you can change it to :

   string filename = 1.txt;
   File.ReadAllLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\" + filename);

Comment: Yes, I fixed that immediately after posting this. I very much appreciate that. :)

And I simply referenced it from within the project. Now, I was curious about that - should I reference just the file name ("WordList.txt") or should I always point it to the proper folder? Which do you think is best?

Also, my monitor is 42" - it isn't too long for me. lol. And when I format it for the purposes of this site, I end up having to hit 'enter', then 'enter' again so that I can indent the line so that it shows up as 'code'. That's why I left it. lol

Thanks a lot, Fab.

Comment: Well, I had answered my own question (above) and simply did a

    File.ReadAllLines("WordList.txt"); and it worked just fine. Or were you referring to something different?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the character(s) used to split the strings, you could use one of the following:

```
        var streamReader = new StreamReader("file");
        var words = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        var wordArray = words.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None); // For words split by lines where you know the format of the line ending
        var wordArray = words.Split(new [] {"\n", "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None); // For words split by lines where the format could be unix or windows
        var wordArray = words.Split(','); // For words split by comma
```

So, for more explination `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` returns a string. This class has many methods as defined in:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx

These methods include a "split" method, which takes either an array of characters (or multiple comma separated characters) (char denoted by single quote (')) or an array of strings with string split options.

In the latter, we define a new array of strings with `new [] { "string1", "string2", "..."}` here the type of the array is implicit, but we could specify `new string[] {...}` if we wanted, or pass in an array of strings we had already defined. The second option is an enum with two values; `None` and `RemoveEmptyEntries`, which are defined here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

There are additional overloads for the `string.split` method (which are in the top link).

Comment: This looks crazy! lol. There are a lot of things I haven't seen here before, but it's nice to be exposed to it now, because I'm gonna' type it in to VSE and see what's up! 

Thank you!

Comment: I have added more explination for your benifit

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help you.

```
private void PutTextIntoArray()
{
    var array = ReadTextFile("C:\\WordList.txt").GetTotalWords();
}    

private static string ReadTextFile(string file)
{
    try
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(file);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ReplaceMultipleSpacesWith(this string text, string newString)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", newString);
    }

    public static string[] GetTotalWords(this string text)
    {
        text = text.Trim().ReplaceMultipleSpacesWith(" ");
        var words = text.Split(' ');
        return words;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This seems a lot more advanced from where I'm sitting now, but I'm taking it all in and this certainly gives me a reference point for in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank all of you for the tremendous help. I had the formatting incorrect, but I guess I understood how it worked after all!! lol. At least it wasn't a misplaced/missing semicolon, yeah? :)

```
  namespace Hangman
   {
class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        //StreamReader myWordList = new StreamReader("WordList.txt");//string stringArray[] = StreamReader(WordList.txt);//.WordList.txt;

        String[] myWordArrays = File.ReadAllLines("WordList.txt");

        Console.WriteLine(myWordArrays[2]);
        Console.ReadLine();


      }


    }
}
```

Thank you all so very much. This fixed it, and it did successfully display the 3rd element (string), which is advice, which happens to be on the third line [2] - perfect. Thank you!!!

Comment: Look here for information on the ReadAllLines method:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx

You may want to add some exception handling

Comment: Oh that's EXCELLENT. Thank you William. That's a wonderful reference.